# Perl regex remove whitespace before close tag

Tags: regex, perl

I need to remove white space before the closing tag using perl regex.

From

```
<span class="inf">cranium </span>
<span class="inf">craniums </span>
<span class="inf">crania </span>
```

to

```
<span class="inf">cranium</span>
<span class="inf">craniums</span>
<span class="inf">crania</span>
```

Using:

```
find . -type f -exec perl -pi -w -e 's/(\s)([\<\/span>])/$2/' \{\} \;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why did you put `\<\/span>` inside `[]`? Get rid of the brackets.

Comment: And there's no need to put `\s` inside a capture group.

Comment: FYI you don't need to escape `{}`.

Answer (score 4):

One can capture a pattern and then in the replacement put back only that, thus effectively removing all other that was matched, as attempted in the question, like so

```
s{\s+(</span>)}{$1}g
```

We match spaces<sup>†</sup> and the pattern `</span>` immediately following them and replace all that with what's been captured in the first (left-most) set of parenthesis (`$1`). That's it.<sup>‡</sup>

The `/g` modifier is there so that this is done throughout the whole string.

Or, using [lookahead](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind)

```
s{\s+(?=</span>)}{}g
```

Now `</span>` pattern isn't "consumed" out of the string but is only "asserted" to be there, following spaces; so we don't need to "put it back" and the empty replacement effectively removes only the  whitespace.

There is also no need to escape `{}` in the `find` command

---

<sup>†</sup> This includes all kinds of "whitespace." See about it for instance [in perlrecharclass](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass#Whitespace)

<sup>‡</sup>  A comment on `[]` used in the question: that's a "character class."  It matches any one of the characters listed inside, with some restrictions and modifications. See linked docs.

So `[\<\/span>]` matches either of the characters: `<`, `/`, `s`, `p`, `a`, `n`, `>`.  The `\` is used to escape `<` and `/` so it isn't matched itself.  (However, escaping those would be unneeded, except for `/` if that is the delimiter for the whole regex.)

See [perlrecharclass](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass), and the tutorial [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut). The full, top-level, reference is [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre).